# How to give url to the image placed outside the folder of document?

Tags: asp.net

My page is placed in a folder client and image in the folder with in the solution.
I have given image url:

```
<img src='<%#"~/productimages/main/" + Eval("PhotoName").ToString().Trim()  %>' alt="No Image" />
```

i want image url to be this

```
http://localhost:1033/productimages/main/13.jpeg
```

but the genrated image url is

```
http://localhost:1033/client/~/productimages/main/13.jpeg
```

why so. Please tell me my mistake

Comment: you can also try `<img src='<%#"../productimages/main/" + Eval("PhotoName").ToString().Trim()  %>' alt="No Image" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src='<%#"/productimages/main/" + Eval("PhotoName").ToString().Trim()  %>' alt="No Image" />
```

Remove the tilde signe before the directory